# Particular websites blocked when using Internet Sharing

Tags: imac, thunderbolt, internet-sharing, target-display

I have the following setup. I have a Macbook Pro with an external monitor plugged into it via HDMI. I then have another external monitor plugged into the Macbook Pro via a Thunderbolt to DVI adapter. Finally I have a thunderbolt cable running from my Macbook Pro to an iMac. I am using this iMac in "Target Display Mode". I also have an ethernet cable plugged into the iMac and the iMac is sharing it's Internet Connection with the Macbook Pro through the thunderbolt bridge. This all works great, except for one very weird thing. There are certain websites that I cannot access. In chrome I get a "ERR TIMED OUT" error when I try to visit certain websites. So far I have only noticed this on two websites:

console.aws.amazon.com
key.com (key.com itself is accessible but there is a bill pay iframe that doesn't load and it gives the same error)

Any suggestions on what could be causing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried connecting to these sites directly with the iMac whose internet connection is being shared jb1785?

I've had some very bad luck with trying to share internet connections (I was trying to share a VPN from a MacMini to an Apple TV or Samsung BluRay player. [Not easy, not high performance and not reliable](https://foliovision.com/2014/02/share-ethernet-osx).

[image]

What do work brilliantly are those little white Apple USB Ethernet Adapters (I'm assuming you don't have Ethernet on that MacBook Pro or you'd be using it). Buy the Apple one as others are either clunky or unreliable (very occasional system crashes but occasional is too much). Bringing in a second Ethernet cable should be easy but if it's not you could drop a small ethernet switch in front of the iMac for very little money for 100 BaseT and not much money for 1000 BaseT.

Daisy chaining sounds like a good idea but you are exponentially increasing your chances for nagging network issues and losing time.

Comment: Yes all of the websites work on the iMac. I guess I will go with the USB ethernet adapter. I don't see another option at this point. Thanks.

Comment: That's the wisest choice jb. For networking, the KISS principle is always valuable if you value your time. Be sure to only buy 5 star products. Dealing with eccentricities is time consuming and not fun. Thanks for accepting my answer (though you didn't upvote it).